# friendly urls with / at the end of the url

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm trying to set up the file "nginx.conf" for friendly urls.

I have the following urls:

```
    /             -> /index.php
    /view/        -> /view/index.php
    /view/client/ -> /view/client.php
    /logout/      -> /logout.php
```

I'm trying with the following code:

```
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri.php $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_pass  php-fpm;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```

Only the url "/" and "/view/" functions. Has anyone ever experienced this?

I searched, but I found nothing with / at the end of the url.

Comment: This is not good application design. Your program should use the Front Controller pattern.

Comment: That is non-standard, and anything non-standard increases risk and maintenance.

Comment: /view/ works because you've got index.php there.

Comment: I understand. any idea to solve this problem without redirect? I do not have much time to change the design.